# How to properly get initial settings to run old python code?

Tags: python, ubuntu, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to run the code that I'm studying. The [original paper](https://aclanthology.org/D19-1310/) and [code](https://github.com/ernestgong/data2text-three-dimensions) are linked here.

As you can see in the GitHub requirements.txt, those packages are quite old versions, especially with torch==0.3.1 and torchtext==0.2.3.

Now, to detail my situation, I'll provide my computer settings. I'm using an old GPU on purpose to fit the old Python packages. If you have any idea to fix this problem with an NVIDIA 3090, that would also be appreciated. I'm also running this in a virtual environment.

```
Ubuntu 22.04
GPU NVIDIA 1080Ti
Python 3.6
CUDA 8.0

pip install six==1.12.0
pip install tqdm==4.31.1
pip install future==0.17.1
pip install pyxdameraulevenshtein==1.5.3
pip install torch==0.3.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html
pip install torchtext==0.2.3
```

After all is set, I could properly run preprocessing for the Rotowire data. However, while trying to run the trained model with 'translate', I encounter the following error:

```
python translate.py -model2 ./paper_model/model.pt -src $BASE/inf_src_test.txt -src_hist $BASE/hist_full/inf_src_test_hist_3.txt -output ./paper_model/model_test.txt -batch_size 10 -max_length 850 -gpu $GPUID -min_length 150
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "translate.py", line 173, in <module>
    main()
  File "translate.py", line 65, in main
    torch.cuda.set_device(opt.gpu)
  File "/home/kkm/anaconda3/envs/table/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 244, in set_device
    torch._C._cuda_setDevice(device)
AttributeError: module 'torch._C' has no attribute '_cuda_setDevice'
```

Please let me know how to run this GitHub code. Thank you.

Comment: In the line where you are installing torch, the url `https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html` seems to indicate that it is a CPU-only build, with no CUDA support. What happens if you change it to `https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch_stable.html`?

Comment: @skandigraun Thank you for your help and sorry for late reply. I'm now trying again with your comment and I'll let you know the result. Thank you!

Comment: @skandigraun Thanks I guess it works properly! I'll show the result below.
"""
python translate.py -model2 ./paper_model/model.pt -src $BASE/inf_src_test.txt -src_hist $BASE/hist_full/inf_src_test_hist_3.txt -output ./paper_model/model_test.txt -batch_size 10 -max_length 850 -gpu $GPUID -min_length 150
"""

Comment: pos emb size is torch.Size([3, 1, 600])
Loading model parameters.
average src size 606.0 728
/data2text/onmt/modules/GlobalAttention.py:177: UserWarning: Implicit dimension choice for softmax has been deprecated. Change the call to include dim=X as an argument.
  align_vectors = self.sm(align.view(batch*targetL, sourceL))
/home/kkm/anaconda_home/data2text/onmt/modules/CopyGenerator.py:91: UserWarning: Implicit dimension choice for softmax has been deprecated. Change the call to include dim=X as an argument.
  prob = F.softmax(logits)
PRED AVG SCORE: -0.2250, PRED PPL: 1.2524

Comment: However I don't understand what the warning means exactly and I'll try to figure it out. It would be also grateful if you don't mind helping this one again.

Comment: perl ref/multi-bleu.perl ref/test.txt < ./paper_model/model_test.txt
BLEU = 16.85, 47.7/20.5/11.1/7.4 (BP=1.000, ratio=1.075, hyp_len=271305, ref_len=252494)

Comment: Don't worry too much about the warning. It says that the syntax has changed, and it will break in the future - but not in your version yet. Personally I would ignore it for now. Otherwise you could try changing [this](https://github.com/ErnestGong/data2text-three-dimensions/blob/master/onmt/modules/GlobalAttention.py#L177) line to `align_vectors = self.sm(align.view(batch*targetL, sourceL), dim=self.dim)` (though verify that you get the same results as without this change. If there is an output diff, I would consider the unchanged version authoritative, as long as it is not completely broken)

Comment: @skandigraun Thankyou so much for your help!